# Why does casting from float to int return the integer part of the float (in C)?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, binary

It's known that after casting a float to int, the int variable gets the integer part of the float variable, discarding the decimal part.

Putting a 32-bit float as an example, which value is -248.75, the value in memory is the following:

```
float_t a = -248.75; // in binary: 11000011 01111000 11000000 00000000
```

As in the following image:

[image]

That binary value represents the following value in decimal:

```
11000011 01111000 11000000 00000000 = 3279470592
```

Then, as far as I know, casting that binary content to (unsigned or not) integer it should return the following values:

```
uint32_t u32 = (uint32_t) a;   -> 3,279,470,592  (**11000011 01111000 11000000 00000000**)
uint16_t u16 = (uint16_t) a;   -> 49152          (00000000 00000000 **11000000 00000000**)
uint8_t  u8  = (uint8_t)  a;   -> 0              (00000000 00000000 00000000 **00000000**)
int32_t  i32 = (int32_t)  a;   -> -1,131,986,944 (**01000011 01111000 11000000 00000000**) (the first bit is the sign)
```

Then, why these variables get 248 value instead? (and vice versa, from integer to float) PD: I am asking for the **technical background**

Comment: Because that's how casting from float to integer types is defined. It's defined that way because it satisfies a real business use case. It will continue to be defined this way because changing it will break existing code and cease to satisfy a real business use case.

Comment: If you want the binary representation you can use a union with uint32_t or just memcpy 4 bytes.

Comment: It seems you want to reinterpret the bytes, not cast the value, because the former does what you describe while the latter, well..., casts the type, which is defined the way you experienced.

Comment: Casting from float to int by saying that it assigns the integer part of the floating-point number to the destination integer variable. This simplification captures the essence of what happens during such a cast: it discards the fractional part and retains the integer component of the floating-point value.

Comment: The example shows you expect to see the bit pattern used to encode `float` but you can't to that by a cast. One way it is to `memcpy(&u32, &f32, sizeof u32);`

Comment: A cast is a way to convert from one type to another. A cast **is not** supposed preserve a binary pattern. Sometimes it do, sometimes it doesn't. And cast between float and integer doesn't preserve bit patterns (except for some special values).

Answer (score 1):

Because casting **is not** copying the binary representation of the float to integer. In converts the the float number (it does not matter how it is represented) to the integer number by discarding the fractional part of the float number

You you want to see the binary representation of the number you need to:

1. Use an `union`:

```
uint32_t viaUnion(float x)
{
    union
    {
        uint32_t u32;
        float f;
    }un = {.f = x};

    return un.u32;
}
```

2. Use `memcpy` function:

```
uint32_t viaMemcpy(float x)
{
    uint32_t u32;

    memcpy(&u32, &x, sizeof(u32));

    return u32;
}
```

To print it:

```
uint32_t printViaUnion(float x)
{
    union
    {
        uint32_t u32;
        uint16_t u16[2];
        uint8_t u8[4];
        float f;
    }un = {.f = x};

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++)
    {
        if(i < sizeof(un.f) / sizeof(un.u8[0])) printf("u8[%zu] = % 3"PRIu8" 0x%02"PRIx8"\t", i, un.u8[i], un.u8[i]);
        if(i < sizeof(un.f) / sizeof(un.u16[0])) printf("u16[%zu] = % 6"PRIu16" 0x%04"PRIx16"\t", i, un.u16[i], un.u16[i]);
        if(i < sizeof(un.f) / sizeof(un.u32)) printf("u32[%zu] = % 10"PRIu32" 0x%08"PRIx32"\t", i, un.u32, un.u32);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return un.u32;
}


int main(void)
{
    printViaUnion(248.75f);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sz1v1r1r4

```
u8[0] =   0 0x00    u16[0] =  49152 0xc000  u32[0] = 1131986944 0x4378c000  
u8[1] = 192 0xc0    u16[1] =  17272 0x4378  
u8[2] = 120 0x78    
u8[3] =  67 0x43
```

or for `-248.75`

```
u8[0] =   0 0x00    u16[0] =  49152 0xc000  u32[0] = 3279470592 0xc378c000  
u8[1] = 192 0xc0    u16[1] =  50040 0xc378  
u8[2] = 120 0x78    
u8[3] = 195 0xc3
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically: because that's what the C language says should be happening. It has nothing to do with the underlying binary representation of types.

A cast is an explicit conversion and so the rules for float to integer conversion apply. C17 6.3.1.4:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

In case you are interested in the pure binary representation, you can inspect any type in C using a pointer to character:

```c
float_t a = -248.75;
unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)&a;
for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++)
{
  printf("%.2X ", ptr[i]);
}
```

Output on little endian machine:

```
00 C0 78 C3
```

Comment: pointer punning cannot be used for anything than char (signed or unsigned). I would suggest `%.2hhX`

Comment: @0___________ And what do you think `unsigned char* ptr` is? The code is fine as per the default argument promotions. `printf` shouldn't be used beyond quick & dirty debugging purposes anyway...

Comment: OP can assume that he can do `short *sptr = (short *)&a` as he wanted to see not only char representations. Just add the remark.

Comment: @0___________ Turns out that I wrote "you can inspect any type in C using a pointer to character" for the reason that you have to use a pointer to character.

Comment: Also, float constant should be `-248.75f`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing casting a value (`(Type)expr`) and accessing through a casted pointer (`*(Type*)&obj`).

Casting causes a conversion. And converting from a floating-point type to an integral is defined as the result of a truncation.<sup>[C17§6.3.1.4¶1]</sup>

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

On the other hand, when you cast a pointer, you end up with a pointer of a different type that points to the same address. So you can "trick" the compiler into accessing an object of one type as another.

So the following would achieve what you want:

```c
float f = -248.75f;
uint32_t u32 = *(uint32_t*)f;
```

However, this is undefined behaviour.<sup>[C17§6.5¶6-7]</sup> But you can also achieve this using a union or `memcpy`.

```c
float f = -248.75f;
uint32_t u32 = ( union { float f; uint32_t u32; } ){ .f = f }.u32;
```